# Who are all the known Blade Runners?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049, blade-runner

In anticipation of the upcoming release of the Blade Runner RPG, I'm becoming as much of a BR completist as I can (books, games, comics, etc).

As I go through this, I want to create a list of **all known Blade Runners.**

Comment: I assume we're excluding normal LAPD personnel like [Nandez](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Nandez) and [Alani Davis](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Alani_Davis) who're helping to find Replicants, but aren't actually blade runners...

Comment: I'm not sure Nandez isn't a Blade Runner. Look at that coat! And why would he be in the room with Joshi and K (and Coco) if he wasn't a Blade Runner?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that entire dept are blade runners or just K within a wider team of cops. Certainly the wiki seems to think that Joshi is the Lt. of the *Retirement Division*, but I can't seem to find any evidence for that

Comment: Perhaps not everyone in the Blade Runner division is a Blade Runner? Maybe Coco only does forensics on replicants? There could be others tasked with surveillance of possible replicant fugitives. But only the ones doing the retiring are called Blade Runners.

Comment: Also just noticed on the Wiki that Alani Davis was once in the BR unit, so she can be added in to the list.

Comment: She failed the Blade Runner Program, hence was never a proper BR - *"Couldn't cut it in the Blade Runner program, could you, Davis?"*

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I have.

**BR (Original Movie)**

- [Rick Deckard](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Rick_Deckard)
- [Dave Holden](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Dave_Holden)
- [Gaff](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Gaff)

**BR 2049**

- [K](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/K)

**BR 2019 (comic)**

- [Aahna "Ash" Ashina](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Aahna_Ashina)
- [Hythe](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Hythe)
- [Lelas](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Lelas)

**BR 2029 (comic)**

- [Hendricks](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Hendriks)
- [Ruskin](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Ruskin)

**BR Origins (comic)**

- [Cal Moreaux](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Cal_Moreaux)

**BR: Black Lotus (animated)**

- [Brooke Marlowe](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Brook_Marlowe)
- [Joseph](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Joseph)
- [Alani Davis](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Alani_Davis?so=search) (Edit: Entered Blade Runner program, but didn't ultimately make it)

**Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?**

- [Franklin Powers](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Franklin_Powers)
- [Phil Resch](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Phil_Resch)

**BR4: Eye and Talon (book)**

- [Iris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner_4:_Eye_and_Talon)

**Dust to Dust (comic prequel to DADoES):**

- [Charlie Victor](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Charlie_Victor)
- [Malcom Reed](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Malcolm_Reed) (by association?)

**Blade Runner Table Top Role Playing Game**

- Leah
- Sandor
- Willem Novak
- Fenna
- Percival
- Oelsen Bakker
- Remy Krumpak

**Video games:**

- [Ray McCoy](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Ray_McCoy)
- [Crystal Steele](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Crystal_Steele)
- [Edison Guzza](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Edison_Guzza)
- [T. Sims](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/T._Sims)
- [Harper](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Harper)
- [R. Taverner](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/R._Taverner)

**Blade Runner Unit Captains**

- [Esper](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Esper_(policeman))
- [Joshi](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Joshi)
- [Harry Bryant](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Harry_Bryant)
- [Lydia Wojciech](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Lydia_Wojciech)
- [Meyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner_4:_Eye_and_Talon)

Comment: Note that Hythe may not have been a legit Blade Runner, or even a legit person

Comment: Was Cal Moreaux a blade runner? I thought he was a cop, then a hired gun for Tyrell.

Comment: This is some fine sleuthing. Stick with me and I'll make a Blade Runner out of you.

Comment: @Valorum - Eye and Talon is the one I can't get my hands on. Anybody have a copy of it they are willing to part with? Willing to pay a reasonable price.

Comment: I'm using "were directed to kill replicants" as a very loose definition of a Blade Runner, so I'll count Hythe.

Comment: Cal Moreaux was sort of a proto-Blade Runner as I understood it. Maybe they weren't called Blade Runners yet.

Comment: I have them, but haven't read the 2029 comics yet.

Comment: @Valorum - Thanks for your help here, much appreciated. Over on the Free League forums there is a Vagrant and a Vader as well, trying to keep all you V's straight.

Comment: INteresting addition. Does the Tabletop RPG have any Voight-Kampff questions?

Comment: It doesn't, but I believe some people in in the BR TTRPG have collected all the known VK questions.